# Printing the sequence in breadth first order using fork()

Tags: c, fork

Given a process tree

```
             A
           /   \
          /     \
         B       C
        / \     / \
       D   E   F   G
```

I am asked to print the sequence in BFS order, i.e A-B-C-D-E-F-G using fork() system call, where each node represents a process with the same parent-child construct as shown in tree(i.e A is parent of B and C, B is parent of D and E like that).

I figured out this solution, but I really don't understand how to make it print recursively.

```
static int count;
char *msg[] = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"};
main(){
  if(!fork()){ //Child 1
    printf("%s\t\t%d\t\t%d\n", msg[count++], (int)getpid(), (int)getppid());
  }
  else{
    if(!fork()){ //Child 2
        printf("%s\t\t%d\t\t%d\n", msg[count++], (int)getpid(), (int)getppid());
    }
  } 
}
```

This logic prints only A-B-C, How to make it recursive so that it will print till G?
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you're meant to use `fork` for this? The only synchronisation you get through fork is by waiting till your children are all dead (unless you're meant to sue semaphores or mutexes) . Your solution could print ACB or ABC if the system came under some stress during the forking.

Comment: Well, If each node represents a process, what else can we use other than `fork` or may be in combination with `fork` ? Kindly suggest.

Comment: you use fork for starting processes. You don't use it for printing trees of processes. There's no way you can guarantee the order of the output without looking. If you want to name the processes somehow in breadth first order, that's different, but isn't what you're asking.

Comment: Yes sir, I never said we use `fork` for printing. My implication is simple, just create processes in such a way that Breadth first order of printing is followed.

Comment: you can't do that without synchronisation of the processes.

Comment: Well, you mean using - `wait()`, `waitpid()` ? What else can we use?

Comment: No, I mean using semaphores and mutexes

Answer (score 1):

Following code does what you need but does not guarantee which leaf will be printed first (print order of the same level).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <linux/wait.h>

typedef struct node {
  char data;
  struct node *left;
  struct node *right;
} node;

void pretty_print(node *nodes[], int size)
{
  int fork_cnt = 0;

  for (int i=0; i < size; i++) {
    if (fork() == 0) {
      // Child path.
      printf("%c (pid: %d, parent: %d)\n", nodes[i]->data, (int)getpid(), (int)getppid());
      node *children_nodes[256];
      int children_sizes = 0;
      if (nodes[i]->left)
    children_nodes[children_sizes++] = nodes[i]->left;
      if (nodes[i]->right)
    children_nodes[children_sizes++] = nodes[i]->right;
      if (children_sizes) {
    if (fork() == 0) {
      pretty_print(children_nodes, children_sizes);
      return;
    }
      }
      return;
    } else {
      // Parent path.
      fork_cnt++;
    }
  }

  for (int i=0; i < fork_cnt; i++) {
    // wait all children.
    int status;
    wait(&status);
  }
}

int main(void) 
{
  node g = {'G', NULL, NULL};
  node f = {'F', NULL, NULL};
  node e = {'E', NULL, NULL};
  node d = {'D', NULL, NULL};
  node b = {'B', &d, &e};
  node c = {'C', &f, &g};
  node a = {'A', &b, &c};

  node *root[1] = {&a};
  pretty_print(root, 1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thats really nice approach actually, but output is varying a lot with every new run. I observed one output where 'D' is printed at the end.