# A breadth-first search in a binary tree of processes using fork

Tags: c, linux, unix, fork, binary-tree

I'm trying to build a binary tree of processes with four levels using **fork()** in [c](/questions/tagged/c).

Something like: [image: this]

My goal is print each number of the process in order (like breadth-first search) For example:

***Output***

```
I'm the process 1
I'm the process 2
I'm the process 3
...
I'm the process 15
```

So I wrote this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

double last;

void new_tree(int);

int main(int narg, char * argv[]){
    int n;

    n = atoi(argv[1]);
    last = pow(2,(n-1));
    new_tree(1);
    return 0;
}

void new_tree(int x){
    char buff[60];
    sprintf(buff, "Im the procces %d with pid %d and ppid %d\n",x,getpid(),getppid());
    write(1,buff,strlen(buff));
    if (x >= last) 
    return;

    if (!fork()){ 
        new_tree(2*x);
        exit(0);
    }

    if(!fork()){ 
        new_tree(2*x+1);
        exit(0);
    }
    wait(NULL);
    wait(NULL);
}
```

But when I run the code (`./tree 4`) I can't control the order of the execution of the processes. My output is a little bit correct but it still in disorder because some processes finished before others in the same level.
Anyone can give me a hand on this?

**My output until now is:**

```
Im the procces 1  
Im the procces 3  
Im the procces 2  
Im the procces 6  
Im the procces 7  
Im the procces 5  
Im the procces 13
Im the procces 15
Im the procces 4
Im the procces 8
Im the procces 14
Im the procces 12
Im the procces 11
Im the procces 10
Im the procces 9
```

It change everytime I execute it.

**EDIT1:**
My code can create binary trees of processes, but the problem is to execute these process in the order that I want.

**EDIT2:**
My output is not a little bit correct. I thought it was but I was wrong.

Comment: I guess you have to use semaphores. I mean iam afraid. Muhehe.

Comment: You should avoid screenshots. Please copy actual code, it's easier to read it from your question, especially if we need to copy it into the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create unix process binary trees?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624325/how-to-create-unix-process-binary-trees)

Comment: post your output

Comment: My output change every time I execute the code. Anyway I put one in the post.

Comment: Where is the code that ensures that process 2 executes before process 3?  There's no attempt to control the sequence of operations, so (surprisingly enough) the operations occur in a random order.

Comment: I also observe that the output you posted is not the output from the code you posted; there are no PID or PPID values shown.  It isn't a huge problem in some respects, but it does undermine your credibility if you show output that clearly isn't from the code you show.

Comment: Yes, That's my question. I don't know how to do that. If I had a binary tree of integers, I would use a queue to control the sequence, but in this case I can't use queue because the nodes are processes.

Comment: We weren't in your class; what techniques were you taught?  What do the lecture notes cover?  Are you meant to be using a file, a fifo, a semaphore, a message queue, a pipe, or some other technique to control the sequence?  Most of those could be used, with greater or less efficiency and simplicity.  But we don't know what's recommended by your course instructor.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler good catch, if this is being given as a homework exercise in tandem with a particular IPC method, then the answer is trivial - use the tool provided!

Comment: As JonathanLeffler said  There's no attempt to control the sequence of operations. but this link may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25686134/printing-the-sequence-in-breadth-first-order-using-fork

Comment: Well, i'm a beginner whit system calls. My instructor just gave us a pdf with exercises to use these functions on my own: fork(), wait(), waitpid(), fflush(), getpid(), getppid(), pipe(), dup(), dup2(), read(), write(), close(), execl(), execv(), execle(), execlp(), execvp(). 
If you guys know a book for beginners about this topic, that would be usefull.

Comment: OK; given the set of functions you have been told about, it seems that you need to use files to control the sequence.  How are you going to do that, do you think?  What information could you write to a file, and read from a file, to ensure you get the right sequence.  It's a pity there's no delay function in the list; I guess you could use one of the `exec*()` functions to run `sleep` for a short time (sub-second if your implementation of `sleep` supports it; otherwise, 1 second).  However, that's me getting ahead of myself — how could you reliably control which process goes next using files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original code almost compiled cleanly under my preferred options, which is a compliment.  I modified it to initialize `n` to `4` and to test `if (narg == 2)` before calculating `n` from `argv[1]`, which prevents the program from crashing if it is run with no arguments.

That version of the program was `ptree29.c`.  When run with argument `3`, it produced results in order, but with argument `4` (or no argument) or argument `5`, the results were radically out of order:

```
$ ptree29 3
Im the procces 1 with pid 92986 and ppid 41763
Im the procces 2 with pid 92987 and ppid 92986
Im the procces 3 with pid 92988 and ppid 92986
Im the procces 4 with pid 92989 and ppid 92987
Im the procces 5 with pid 92991 and ppid 92987
Im the procces 6 with pid 92990 and ppid 92988
Im the procces 7 with pid 92992 and ppid 92988
$ ptree29 5
Im the procces 1 with pid 92993 and ppid 41763
Im the procces 2 with pid 92994 and ppid 92993
Im the procces 3 with pid 92995 and ppid 92993
Im the procces 4 with pid 92996 and ppid 92994
Im the procces 6 with pid 92997 and ppid 92995
Im the procces 5 with pid 92998 and ppid 92994
Im the procces 7 with pid 92999 and ppid 92995
Im the procces 8 with pid 93000 and ppid 92996
Im the procces 12 with pid 93001 and ppid 92997
Im the procces 10 with pid 93002 and ppid 92998
Im the procces 9 with pid 93003 and ppid 92996
Im the procces 13 with pid 93004 and ppid 92997
Im the procces 14 with pid 93005 and ppid 92999
Im the procces 11 with pid 93006 and ppid 92998
Im the procces 16 with pid 93007 and ppid 93000
Im the procces 24 with pid 93008 and ppid 93001
Im the procces 15 with pid 93009 and ppid 92999
Im the procces 25 with pid 93014 and ppid 93001
Im the procces 18 with pid 93011 and ppid 93003
Im the procces 28 with pid 93015 and ppid 93005
Im the procces 20 with pid 93010 and ppid 93002
Im the procces 26 with pid 93012 and ppid 93004
Im the procces 17 with pid 93013 and ppid 93000
Im the procces 22 with pid 93016 and ppid 93006
Im the procces 21 with pid 93017 and ppid 93002
Im the procces 30 with pid 93019 and ppid 93009
Im the procces 27 with pid 93018 and ppid 93004
Im the procces 19 with pid 93020 and ppid 93003
Im the procces 29 with pid 93021 and ppid 93005
Im the procces 23 with pid 93022 and ppid 93006
Im the procces 31 with pid 93023 and ppid 93009
$
```

You need to devise a mechanism to to control the sequence in which the processes print their "I'm the process" messages.  With the system calls you've been given to use (*`fork()`, `wait()`, `waitpid()`, `fflush()`, `getpid()`, `getppid()`, `pipe()`, `dup()`, `dup2()`, `read()`, `write()`, `close()`, `execl()`, `execv()`, `execle()`, `execlp()`, `execvp()`*) — I hope that using [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) too isn't going to be a show-stopper — then you can create a file which contains the number of the last process to print its "I'm the process" message.  Each process will wait until it is its turn — which it knows by checking that the number in the file is its number minus one.  Other processes can read the file too.  When the process has written its "I'm the process" message, it launches its two children, then waits for them to complete.

I elected to use my `stderr.c` and `stderr.h` code (available from Github at https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) because the functions therein (whose names all start with `err_`) make it trivial to log errors and messages with the PID and the time, which is invaluable in contexts such as this with a lot of processes running at once.  Another advantage is that it gives one-line error handling, rather than 3 or more lines per error if you don't have such functions — which makes me less reluctant to write the error handling code.

The code also uses [`nanosleep()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nanosleep.html) so that if a process reads a number that's too small (or too large — but the code doesn't handle that error case), it sleeps for one millisecond before retrying.  This limits the rate of retries sufficiently.

The new code is in the source for `ptree17.c`:

```
/* SO 4574-5483 */
#include "stderr.h"
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static const char filename[] = "pt-next.dat";
static double last = 0.0;

static void new_tree(int num);
static void write_file(int num);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    err_setarg0(argv[0]);
    err_setlogopts(ERR_PID|ERR_MILLI);

    int n = 4;
    if (argc == 2)
        n = atoi(argv[1]);
    write_file(0);
    last = pow(2, (n - 1));
    new_tree(1);
    return 0;
}

static void write_file(int num)
{
    int fd = open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0600);
    if (fd < 0)
        err_syserr("failed to create file '%s' for writing\n", filename);
    if (write(fd, &num, sizeof(num)) != sizeof(num))
        err_syserr("failed to write %d to file '%s'\n", num, filename);
    close(fd);
    err_remark("wrote %2d to '%s'\n", num, filename);
}

static int read_file(void)
{
    int num = -1;
    int fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd > 0)
    {
        if (read(fd, &num, sizeof(num)) != sizeof(num))
            num = -1;
        close(fd);
    }
    err_remark("read %2d from '%s'\n", num, filename);
    return num;
}

static void wait_for_turn(int num)
{
    struct timespec ms = { .tv_sec = 0, .tv_nsec = 1000000 };
    while (read_file() != num - 1)
    {
        err_remark("dozing\n");
        nanosleep(&ms, 0);
    }
}

static void new_tree(int x)
{
    char buff[60];
    err_remark("Process = %2d\n", x);
    wait_for_turn(x);
    sprintf(buff, "I'm process %2d with pid %5d and ppid %5d\n", x, getpid(), getppid());
    write(1, buff, strlen(buff));
    write_file(x);
    if (x >= last)
        return;

    if (!fork())
    {
        new_tree(2 * x);
        exit(0);
    }

    if (!fork())
    {
        new_tree(2 * x + 1);
        exit(0);
    }

    int corpse, status;
    while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
        err_remark("child %5d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
}
```

Example output 1 — errors sent to `/dev/null`:

```
$ ptree17 5 2>/dev/null
I'm process  1 with pid 93174 and ppid 41763
I'm process  2 with pid 93175 and ppid 93174
I'm process  3 with pid 93176 and ppid 93174
I'm process  4 with pid 93177 and ppid 93175
I'm process  5 with pid 93178 and ppid 93175
I'm process  6 with pid 93179 and ppid 93176
I'm process  7 with pid 93180 and ppid 93176
I'm process  8 with pid 93181 and ppid 93177
I'm process  9 with pid 93182 and ppid 93177
I'm process 10 with pid 93183 and ppid 93178
I'm process 11 with pid 93184 and ppid 93178
I'm process 12 with pid 93185 and ppid 93179
I'm process 13 with pid 93186 and ppid 93179
I'm process 14 with pid 93187 and ppid 93180
I'm process 15 with pid 93188 and ppid 93180
I'm process 16 with pid 93189 and ppid 93181
I'm process 17 with pid 93190 and ppid 93181
I'm process 18 with pid 93191 and ppid 93182
I'm process 19 with pid 93192 and ppid 93182
I'm process 20 with pid 93193 and ppid 93183
I'm process 21 with pid 93194 and ppid 93183
I'm process 22 with pid 93195 and ppid 93184
I'm process 23 with pid 93196 and ppid 93184
I'm process 24 with pid 93197 and ppid 93185
I'm process 25 with pid 93198 and ppid 93185
I'm process 26 with pid 93199 and ppid 93186
I'm process 27 with pid 93200 and ppid 93186
I'm process 28 with pid 93201 and ppid 93187
I'm process 29 with pid 93203 and ppid 93187
I'm process 30 with pid 93202 and ppid 93188
I'm process 31 with pid 93204 and ppid 93188
$
```

Example output 2 — standard error visible:

```
$ ptree17
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.798 - pid=93210: wrote  0 to 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.799 - pid=93210: Process =  1
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.799 - pid=93210: read  0 from 'pt-next.dat'
I'm process  1 with pid 93210 and ppid 41763
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.800 - pid=93210: wrote  1 to 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.801 - pid=93211: Process =  2
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.801 - pid=93211: read  1 from 'pt-next.dat'
I'm process  2 with pid 93211 and ppid 93210
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.801 - pid=93212: Process =  3
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.801 - pid=93212: read -1 from 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.801 - pid=93212: dozing
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.804 - pid=93211: wrote  2 to 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.804 - pid=93212: read  2 from 'pt-next.dat'
I'm process  3 with pid 93212 and ppid 93210
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.804 - pid=93212: wrote  3 to 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.804 - pid=93213: Process =  4
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.805 - pid=93213: read  3 from 'pt-next.dat'
I'm process  4 with pid 93213 and ppid 93211
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.805 - pid=93214: Process =  6
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.805 - pid=93215: Process =  5
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.805 - pid=93216: Process =  7
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.805 - pid=93213: wrote  4 to 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.805 - pid=93216: read  4 from 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.805 - pid=93214: read  4 from 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.805 - pid=93215: read  4 from 'pt-next.dat'
I'm process  5 with pid 93215 and ppid 93211
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.805 - pid=93216: dozing
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.805 - pid=93214: dozing
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.805 - pid=93215: wrote  5 to 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.806 - pid=93217: Process =  8
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.806 - pid=93217: read  5 from 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.806 - pid=93217: dozing
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.806 - pid=93218: Process =  9
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.806 - pid=93219: Process = 10
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.806 - pid=93219: read  5 from 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.806 - pid=93218: read  5 from 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.806 - pid=93219: dozing
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.806 - pid=93218: dozing
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.806 - pid=93220: Process = 11
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.806 - pid=93220: read  5 from 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.806 - pid=93216: read  5 from 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.806 - pid=93220: dozing
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.806 - pid=93216: dozing
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.806 - pid=93214: read  5 from 'pt-next.dat'
I'm process  6 with pid 93214 and ppid 93212
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.807 - pid=93214: wrote  6 to 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.807 - pid=93217: read  6 from 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.807 - pid=93217: dozing
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.807 - pid=93218: read  6 from 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.807 - pid=93219: read  6 from 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.807 - pid=93218: dozing
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.807 - pid=93221: Process = 12
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.807 - pid=93219: dozing
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.808 - pid=93221: read  6 from 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.808 - pid=93220: read  6 from 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.808 - pid=93221: dozing
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.808 - pid=93220: dozing
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.808 - pid=93222: Process = 13
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.808 - pid=93216: read  6 from 'pt-next.dat'
I'm process  7 with pid 93216 and ppid 93212
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.808 - pid=93222: read  6 from 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.808 - pid=93222: dozing
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.808 - pid=93216: wrote  7 to 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.808 - pid=93217: read  7 from 'pt-next.dat'
I'm process  8 with pid 93217 and ppid 93213
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.809 - pid=93217: wrote  8 to 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.809 - pid=93218: read  8 from 'pt-next.dat'
I'm process  9 with pid 93218 and ppid 93213
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.809 - pid=93223: Process = 14
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.809 - pid=93218: wrote  9 to 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.809 - pid=93223: read -1 from 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.809 - pid=93219: read  8 from 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.809 - pid=93221: read  9 from 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.809 - pid=93224: Process = 15
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.809 - pid=93223: dozing
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.809 - pid=93219: dozing
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.809 - pid=93213: child 93217 exited with status 0x0000
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.809 - pid=93222: read  9 from 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.809 - pid=93224: read  9 from 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.809 - pid=93220: read  9 from 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.809 - pid=93221: dozing
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.809 - pid=93224: dozing
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.809 - pid=93222: dozing
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.810 - pid=93220: dozing
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.810 - pid=93213: child 93218 exited with status 0x0000
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.810 - pid=93211: child 93213 exited with status 0x0000
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.810 - pid=93223: read  9 from 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.810 - pid=93219: read  9 from 'pt-next.dat'
I'm process 10 with pid 93219 and ppid 93215
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.811 - pid=93223: dozing
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.811 - pid=93219: wrote 10 to 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.811 - pid=93224: read 10 from 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.811 - pid=93222: read 10 from 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.811 - pid=93220: read 10 from 'pt-next.dat'
I'm process 11 with pid 93220 and ppid 93215
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.811 - pid=93221: read 10 from 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.811 - pid=93224: dozing
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.811 - pid=93221: dozing
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.811 - pid=93222: dozing
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.812 - pid=93220: wrote 11 to 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.812 - pid=93215: child 93219 exited with status 0x0000
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.812 - pid=93223: read 11 from 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.812 - pid=93223: dozing
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.812 - pid=93215: child 93220 exited with status 0x0000
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.812 - pid=93211: child 93215 exited with status 0x0000
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.813 - pid=93210: child 93211 exited with status 0x0000
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.813 - pid=93222: read 11 from 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.813 - pid=93224: read 11 from 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.813 - pid=93222: dozing
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.813 - pid=93224: dozing
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.813 - pid=93221: read 11 from 'pt-next.dat'
I'm process 12 with pid 93221 and ppid 93214
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.813 - pid=93221: wrote 12 to 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.813 - pid=93223: read 12 from 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.813 - pid=93223: dozing
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.814 - pid=93214: child 93221 exited with status 0x0000
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.814 - pid=93222: read 12 from 'pt-next.dat'
I'm process 13 with pid 93222 and ppid 93214
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.815 - pid=93222: wrote 13 to 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.815 - pid=93224: read 13 from 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.815 - pid=93223: read 13 from 'pt-next.dat'
I'm process 14 with pid 93223 and ppid 93216
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.815 - pid=93224: dozing
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.815 - pid=93214: child 93222 exited with status 0x0000
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.815 - pid=93212: child 93214 exited with status 0x0000
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.816 - pid=93223: wrote 14 to 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.816 - pid=93224: read 14 from 'pt-next.dat'
I'm process 15 with pid 93224 and ppid 93216
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.816 - pid=93216: child 93223 exited with status 0x0000
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.816 - pid=93224: wrote 15 to 'pt-next.dat'
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.817 - pid=93216: child 93224 exited with status 0x0000
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.817 - pid=93212: child 93216 exited with status 0x0000
ptree17: 2017-08-17 20:03:20.817 - pid=93210: child 93212 exited with status 0x0000
$
```

As you can see, the "I'm the process" messages are printed strictly in sequence.  And it doesn't take long for the whole program to run — about 19 ms in total from first to last printed message.

The log with standard error for `ptree17 5` is too big for an answer on SO.